# Why webView do not fit exactly in XCODE simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

It's first time i have touched Mac and have tried to develop a small application which has a webView and must display the website on it.

Fortunately i am able to display it on web view but unfortunately that website do not fit exactly on the simulator. I mean the website width is more and and content  cross the boundary of simulator width and contents spreaded randomly on webview.

I tried various things on google search and the one that could work is this (non commented):

```
//    
//  ViewController.m    
//  WebView    
//      
#import "ViewController.h"     
@interface ViewController ()
@end    
@implementation ViewController    
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];    
    /*    //commented because it do not fit the website in simulator
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://stackoverflow.com";    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];    
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];    
    */

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://stackoverflow.com";    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding] error:nil];    
    NSRange range = [html rangeOfString:@"<body"];  
    if(range.location != NSNotFound)    
    {    
        // Adjust style for mobile    
        float inset = 60;    
        NSString *style = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>div {max-width: %fpx;}</style>", self.view.bounds.size.width - inset];    
        html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", [html substringToIndex:range.location], style, [html substringFromIndex:range.location]];   
    }       
    [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:url];      
}   

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView    
{    
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"from appl will enter webViewDidFinishLoad"  message:@"from appl  will enter webViewDidFinishLoad"  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];    

    CGSize contentSize = theWebView.scrollView.contentSize;    
    CGSize viewSize = theWebView.bounds.size;       
    float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;   
    theWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
    theWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
    theWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;
}
@end
```

and  controller.h is :

```
////////////////////////    
//    
//  ViewController.h    
//  WebView    
//  
//    
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
@interface ViewController : UIViewController    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;    
@end
```

This code fits the webiste in my view (non commented part of code only) but there are 2 problems :

(1)The website fits well in simulator of XCode (on inset=60 value) but when i click on any tab/button in this website which has fit properly then if that tab/button opens a new link then this new link page again go beyond the width of simulator (so the new page obtained is again not fitting in simulator width).

(2) I feel that this way of exactly fitting is not good one as we have taken the size statically (inset) which is not a good way, for example in case if setup is tested in various versions of IPhone then it may not fit perfectly. **I have used this way because only this way could work for me**. I have already tried  `_webView.frame=self.view.bounds;` but out of luck.

**Could someone please help me in achieving my target ?**